# Asus X200M, Super Slow WiFi Connection with Realtek RTL8188EE

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, asus, realtek

I just got this new **Asus X200M** laptop, dual-boot Windows 8 with Ubuntu. The problem is that I am having some wireless- internet issues when I log-on with Ubuntu. When I go to, http://www.speedtest.net/ , the results are following:
Pint: 15ms
Download Speed: 0.8-2.5Mbps (I have tries for a few times)
Upload Speed: 3-6Mbps
Also, I can't access to any public WiFi, both the one you enter password in network setting and in a browser.
In contrast, when I use Win8, I get 40-50Mbps for both Download speed and Upload speed. Note, I haven't tried to use Wins8 access public WiFi.

Here are some information about my X200M:

```
 OS: Ubuntu 14.04 trusty (x86-64)
 Kernel: 3.16.0-43-generic 

lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation ValleyView SSA-CUnit (rev 0e)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation ValleyView Gen7 (rev 0e)
00:13.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation ValleyView 6-Port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 0e)
00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation ValleyView SEC (rev 0e)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation ValleyView High Definition Audio Controller (rev 0e)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation ValleyView PCI Express Root Port (rev 0e)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation ValleyView PCI Express Root Port (rev 0e)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation ValleyView PCI Express Root Port (rev 0e)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation ValleyView USB Enhanced Host Controller (rev 0e)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation ValleyView Power Control Unit (rev 0e)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation ValleyView SMBus Controller (rev 0e)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5286 (rev 01)
03:00.2 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 06)

iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"gibe.de.wifi.b0ss"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 20:25:64:F8:58:A0   
          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=68/70  Signal level=-42 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:2789   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

I have tried many different methods. None of them works.

Thank you for any input, and if you want any info of my machine, please let me know, and please also tell me the command line for that. 
Thanks

Comment: Which methods did you try?

Comment: 14.10 is not supported any more. And it won't solve your issue at all. I suggest upgrading kernel in 14.04 to `lts-vivid` at least.

Comment: *** @Pilot6 I really tried a lot, a lot (I spent at least 5 hours into it, though I am just a chill computer user). Let's just say this, I have seen your name on few different webs. Right now, I am trying to upgrade Ubuntu from 14.04 LTS to 14.10 without reason. I am not sure if you can help me find a set solution from you. I have tried: 1) the one by replacing 
"hosts:          files dns"
2) some code (I tried many, including some backport, etc) , then sudo modprobe -v rtl8188

Answer (score 0):

If you did not upgrade to 14.10 yet, you can try another driver

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms linux-firmware
```

Comment: I updated to 14.10, and this code does not work. Is there anything you would suggest? @Pilot6